# SVD function in R. I want to get the singular values $d from a list of datasets. I want to put it in a table form

Tags: r, svd

I want to use the svd function to get the singular values of a large datasets in a list.
When I use the svd function in a single matrix, I am able to use $d and get the values, but for the list I cannot get the output.
Here is the code for a matrix and the output.

```
     tb = matrix(c(64,  112,    59, 174,    111,    37,
              39,   135,    115,    92, 161,    70,
              93,   119,    50, 142,    20, 114,
              149,  191,    62, 17, 145,    21,
              60,   37, 29, 74, 42, 242), nrow = 5, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)




## Compute SVD of tb
#
     my_svd = svd(tb)

## Retrieve (save) singular values
#
     sv = my_svd$d

## Compute ratio between "1st/2nd" & "2nd/3rd" singular values
#
    ratios = matrix(c(sv[1]/sv[2], sv[2]/sv[3]), nrow = 1)
    colnames(ratios) = c("sv1/sv2", "sv2/sv3")

## Print ratios
ratios
```

How do I apply this to the list of dataset?
my current code

```
     svdresult <- lapply(d1,svd)
     svdresult
```

### d1 is my list of dataset

How do I get svdresult$d on the list of datasets.

```
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: And make a table just like the code above please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?

```r
get_svd_ratios <- function(data) {
  sv = svd(data)$d
  n = length(sv)
  ratios = matrix(sv[1:(n - 1)] / sv[2:n] , nrow = 1)
  names = paste(
    paste0("sv", 1:(n - 1)), 
    paste0("sv", 2:n), 
    sep = "/"
  )
  colnames(ratios) = names
  return(ratios)
}

lapply(list(tb), get_svd_ratios)

# [[1]]
#       sv1/sv2  sv2/sv3 sv3/sv4  sv4/sv5
# [1,] 2.261771 1.680403 1.29854 2.682195
```

Comment: Thank so much. It work. However, I just need the first two. i.e. sv1/sv2, sv2/sv3. How do I adjust the code please.

Comment: I have managed to adjust the code. Thanks a lot.